# Get value from a key value pair separated with pipe

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing

I have a string as below

```
Delete :xna.del|mode:Full|Execution: loaded
```

I need my output to be stored in 3 parameters.
for an example

```
a=xna.del
b=Full
c=loaded
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`, storing the result in an associative array:

```
$ string='Delete :xna.del|mode:Full|Execution: loaded'
$ IFS=':|'
$ set -o extendedglob
$ typeset -A field=( ${=string//[[:space:]]#:[[:space:]]#/:} )
$ typeset -p field
typeset -A field=( [Delete]=xna.del [Execution]=loaded [mode]=Full )
$ print -r -- $field[mode]
Full
```

Answer (score 0):

so i guess the Word in front of ":" has no concern for you?

Try this solution with an Array for all Values

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
TEXT="Delete :xna.del|mode:Full|Execution: loaded"
MYVAR=( $(tr '|' '\n' <<< "${TEXT}" |cut -d: -f2) )

#Checks on the result
echo MYVAR has "${#MYVAR[@]}" entries
#single-Access
echo "${MYVAR[0]}"
echo "${MYVAR[1]}"
echo "${MYVAR[2]}"
#formated output
printf "\t%s\n" "${MYVAR[@]}"
#iterate again to work with it?
for value in "${MYVAR[@]}"; do echo "$value"; done
```

Comment: That looks more like zsh syntax than bash syntax. In `bash`, you'd need `"${MYVAR[0]}"`, quote all the expansions except `$(tr...)` and disable globbing.